# Are two angles of a cone the same? If not, what is relationship between them?

Tags: geometry, solid-of-revolution

Are the angles $\theta$ and $\alpha$ the same? [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txDV7.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same, but related via $r$, the radius of the cone base,

$$\theta L = 2\pi r =2\pi L\sin \frac\alpha2$$

or, $$\theta = 2\pi \sin\frac\alpha2$$