# I need help with constructing a "3D" cone out of paper with precise angles.

Tags: geometry, area, solid-geometry, solid-of-revolution

I just can't seem to wrap my head around it. - I need to make an accurate and precise model of a cone out of paper, with it's angle around the cap/spike equal to $90^° $ - I know it seems obvious but getting the Side Area to stick itself into a 3D model is going very wrong so far for me - even though I used this relationship:$$\theta = 2\pi \sin\frac\alpha2$$ image [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txDV7.jpg)

Comment: someone suggested it to me here [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433961/are-two-angles-of-a-cone-the-same-if-not-what-is-relationship-between-them)

Comment: What is $\alpha?$

Comment: @RossMillikan check link i provided above your comment - alpha is basically an angle…. And I don't know which anymore… because if it was the angle of  
90°, then i would get a cone with the angle that i want to be 90° to actually be about 20° - which is sad considering that I didn't make a reasoning mistake…?

Comment: Are you aware that $\theta$ in that formula is given in radians (not degrees)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Sorry, my mistake. Corrected answer

$ L =\frac{R}{sin(\alpha/2)}$ . Cut a sector of circle with radius $L$ and angle it makes

$ \theta = 360^o \dfrac{R}{L}$

Answer (score -1):

[image]

See the figure.. It explains. Take a rectangular paper with one side $2 \pi R$.

Now from cone figure

$ L =\frac{R}{sin(\alpha/2)}$

Now from paper figure what is $P$?

Simply

$P = \sqrt{L^2-(\pi R)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{R^2}{sin^2(\alpha/2)^2}-(\pi R)^2}$

$P = R \sqrt{cosec^2(\alpha/2)-\pi ^2}$

Draw a perpendicular bisector in paper with length $P$, Complete triangle , cut and glue. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! You don't know how much trouble I had with it!

Comment: However the second picture has a line with its length $2\pi r$ which is not really right, because this triangle has a circumference R, so I suppose second figure with the height P is about the sector of a circle, right?

Comment: Plane development of the cone is not a triangle.

Comment: +1 Thank you! My bad